# Swedish BankID Python Animated QR code generation with hmac

Tags: python, django, qr-code, hmac, bankid

I'm developing a Django project that will use BankID for authorization and digitally sign. I am using [pybankid](https://github.com/hbldh/pybankid), and I have nothing but nice things to say about that project. My problem lies with trying to use the code provided by bankIDs documentation.

[QRCode Docs](https://www.bankid.com/utvecklare/guider/teknisk-integrationsguide/qrkoder)

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
 
qr_start_token = rp_response["qrStartToken"]
# "67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8"
 
qr_start_secret = rp_response["qrStartSecret"]
# "d28db9a7-4cde-429e-a983-359be676944c"
 
order_time = time.time()
# (The time in seconds when the response from the BankID service was delivered)
 
qr_time = str(int(time.time() - order_time))
# ("0" or another string with a higher number depending on order_time and current time)
 
qr_auth_code = hmac.new(qr_start_secret, qr_time, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
# "dc69358e712458a66a7525beef148ae8526b1c71610eff2c16cdffb4cdac9bf8" (qr_time="0")
# "949d559bf23403952a94d103e67743126381eda00f0b3cbddbf7c96b1adcbce2" (qr_time="1")
# "a9e5ec59cb4eee4ef4117150abc58fad7a85439a6a96ccbecc3668b41795b3f3" (qr_time="2")
# (64 chars hex)
 
qr_data = str.join(".", "bankid", qr_start_token, qr_time, qr_auth_code)
# "bankid.67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8.0.dc69358e712458a66a7525beef148ae8526b1c71610eff2c16cdffb4cdac9bf8" (qr_time="0")
# "bankid.67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8.1.949d559bf23403952a94d103e67743126381eda00f0b3cbddbf7c96b1adcbce2" (qr_time="1")
# "bankid.67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8.2.a9e5ec59cb4eee4ef4117150abc58fad7a85439a6a96ccbecc3668b41795b3f3" (qr_time="2")
```

I get TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str', when I try to convert qr_start_secret to bytes I get Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing. I'm at a loss. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Here is my current code, and it works. Currently struggling with how to render a constantly changing QR code value client side, as context will only transfer static values.

```
if request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
 ua_string = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
 user_agent = parse(ua_string)
 if user_agent.is_pc:
                        
  status=client.collect(order_ref=auth["orderRef"])["status"]
                        order_time = time.time()
                        while status == "pending":

  qr_start_token = auth["qrStartToken"]

  qr_start_secret = auth["qrStartSecret"]

  qr_time = str(int(time.time() - order_time))

  qr_auth_code = hmac.new(qr_start_secret.encode(), qr_time.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

  qr_data = ".".join(["bankid", qr_start_token, qr_time, qr_auth_code])

  print(f'qr_data: {qr_data}')

                            
  status=client.collect(order_ref=auth["orderRef"])["status"]

  print(status)

  qr = segno.make(qr_data)
  qr.save('media/img/temp/' + personal_number + '.svg')

  if status == "complete":
   print("Logged on")
   dj_login(request, user)
   return render(request, 'home/auth-login-Success.html')

  time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with their sample code

1. It looks like `qr_start_token` and `qr_start_secret` are strings.
2. `str.join` will raise error for receiving 4 arguments

Try:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
 
qr_start_token = "67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8"
 
qr_start_secret = "d28db9a7-4cde-429e-a983-359be676944c"
 
order_time = time.time()
# (The time in seconds when the response from the BankID service was delivered)
 
qr_time = str(int(time.time() - order_time))
# ("0" or another string with a higher number depending on order_time and current time)
print(f'qr_time: {qr_time}')
qr_auth_code = hmac.new(qr_start_secret.encode(), qr_time.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
# "dc69358e712458a66a7525beef148ae8526b1c71610eff2c16cdffb4cdac9bf8" (qr_time="0")
# "949d559bf23403952a94d103e67743126381eda00f0b3cbddbf7c96b1adcbce2" (qr_time="1")
# "a9e5ec59cb4eee4ef4117150abc58fad7a85439a6a96ccbecc3668b41795b3f3" (qr_time="2")
# (64 chars hex)

print(f'qr_auth_code: {qr_auth_code}')
print(qr_auth_code == "dc69358e712458a66a7525beef148ae8526b1c71610eff2c16cdffb4cdac9bf8")
 
qr_data = str.join(".", ["bankid", qr_start_token, qr_time, qr_auth_code])
# or better
# qr_data = ".".join(["bankid", qr_start_token, qr_time, qr_auth_code])

# "bankid.67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8.0.dc69358e712458a66a7525beef148ae8526b1c71610eff2c16cdffb4cdac9bf8" (qr_time="0")
# "bankid.67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8.1.949d559bf23403952a94d103e67743126381eda00f0b3cbddbf7c96b1adcbce2" (qr_time="1")
# "bankid.67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8.2.a9e5ec59cb4eee4ef4117150abc58fad7a85439a6a96ccbecc3668b41795b3f3" (qr_time="2")

print(f'qr_data: {qr_data}')
```

output:

```
qr_time: 0
qr_auth_code: dc69358e712458a66a7525beef148ae8526b1c71610eff2c16cdffb4cdac9bf8
True
qr_data: bankid.67df3917-fa0d-44e5-b327-edcc928297f8.0.dc69358e712458a66a7525beef148ae8526b1c71610eff2c16cdffb4cdac9bf8
```

Comment: Heh, I need 15 rep to upvote you. I think that you have the right answer and I wonder why the demo code was so poorly written. It feels like someone converted it from another language and didn't test it. I am going to render it as an animated QR code and see if I can auth from the BankID mobile app.

Comment: I agree it was not tested.  And you can [accept an answer that solves your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Probably you can contact them and notify for this problem with their sample code.

Comment: It did solve that problem, but opened up a can of worms... Like how do I render an ever changing QR code from Django views onto a page. I don't want to render the secret code in JS and perform the same function there. Sigh, more to learn.